# Java Regular Expression works with online testing, but not in practice

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that works when I test it on sites like this: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/. However, within my code it doesn't work. Any suggestions as to why?

**Target Text:** \vdiarctest12\test\2014\Trad 2014Q1\Step 1\United_Traditional_v2306_03_18_2014_1340.pfd

Incoorporated into Java:

```
if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches("^([A-Za-z]):.*")) {
if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches("\\\\vdiarc.*[0-9]\\.*")) {
status = "MAPPING ERROR: Please submit a file from a mapped drive (i.e. K:\\).";
request.setAttribute(FairValConstants.status, status);
throw new InvalidFileMoveException(FairValConstants.MAKE_VALID_SELECTION);
} 
}
```

My code checks to see if the text in the bean *doesn't* match the regular expression. When I test the expression it finds everything, so by putting an ! before it, I would have thought it would work the way I want.

Suggestion?
Thanks!

**Edit**

Changed my code, sorry for the formating.  Here is the purpose of my regex.  My users are submitting a file, they can either use a mapped drive or type in the location `\\vdiarctest01\test\` etc.  I am checking to see if they submitted a mapped drive, if not check to see if they typed it in, if not throw the error.  Otherwise contiue on.

Comment: What's your original regex?

Comment: \\\\vdiarc.*[0-9]\\.*

Comment: Is your input string on several lines?

Comment: Nope. It is a single line.

Comment: Still waiting for what you're actually trying to assert. Otherwise it's us looking at your RegEx and guessing what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post, I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
\\\\vdiarc.*[0-9]\\.*
                   ^^
```

You can remove the `\\` before the `.`

Or you can add a `.` after the `\\.`

So it will be

```
\\\\vdiarc.*[0-9]\\..*
```

Comment: I still have the same issue.  Could it be the way my `if` statement is coded?

Comment: To match the `\\` before the `vdiarc` you have to use `\\\\\\\\ ` in the regex for example `\\\\\\\\vdiarc`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it non-greedy:

```
"\\\\vdiarc.*?[0-9]\\..*"
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iO9mX1)

Comment: @staples: If you're trying to match `\\vdiarctest12\test` then regex will be: `"\\\\\\\\vdiarc.*?[0-9]\\..*"`